# react nativeでコンポーネントのアップデートの仕方について教えてください。

Tags: reactjs, react-native

初めまして。
お世話になります。

React Nativeのことで質問です。
React-Native-cliを利用してプロジェクトを作成したのですが、package.json内のreactのバージョンが^16.3.0-alpha.1となってしまっている影響か、次のようなWarningが出るようになりました。

> Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and will be removed
>   in the next major version. Use static getDerivedStateFromProps
>   instead.
>       Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary
>   workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount.

Warningの内容は、ライフサイクルで使用される関数が変わるので変更するように、とのことですが、npmを利用すればいいのかどうしていいのか全くわかりません。
これらのWarningを解決する方法をGoogle等で検索してみたのですが、自分では見つけることができませんでした。

もし解決方法をご存知であれば、ご教授くださると大変助かります。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まだ新しいので情報が少ないですね。自分も探り探り使っています。
[What’s new in React 16.3(.0-alpha)](https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b) によると、

- `componentWillMount` は `componentDidMount` に変更
- `componentWillUpdate` は `componentDidUpdate` に変更
- `componentWillReceiveProps` は新たに追加された `static getDerivedStateFromProps` を使う

のが良いようです。特にnpmの追加は要りません。

プロジェクトを新規作成されたとのことなので、上記の通り対応していけば良いでしょう。
既存のプロジェクトの場合、これに対応しようとすると、影響範囲が大きすぎるので、しばらくは対応せず様子見でも良いかもしれません。
16.3の正式リリース時に経緯の詳細や対策が発表されるのではないかと思います。

Warningにもある通り、メジャーバージョンが16のあいだは`componentWillMount`等がそのまま使えます。大量のWarningが気になるようであれば、頭に`UNSAFE_`を付けて、`UNSAFE_componentWillMount`等を使うことで、Warningを出なくすることもできるようです。

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18175

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18165#issuecomment-369907978
こちらでも話題になっていますね

自作の Components では will を使わないようにしつつ、既存の components からでるエラーは無視するのが現在のところ得策のようです、、

Comment: なるほど。現在のところ、react-native-cliを利用する場合は、とりあえず無視がいいんですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 16.3に関する記事が上がっていたので、リンクを載せておきます。
[React v16.3.0: New lifecycles and context API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes), 
[Update on Async Rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)